# The configuration key is unsupported for definition "parameters"

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

I'm using Symfony DI component. I'm trying to pass string parameter into service constructor as follows:

```
services:
   parameters:
        config.directory: './../../../'
   _defaults:
        public: true
   settings:
        class: Bar\Foo\Service
        arguments: ['%config.directory%']
```

I'm compiling container by:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($containerBuilder, new FileLocator($dir));
$loader->load('services.yaml');
$containerBuilder->compile();
```

Exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
>   The configuration key "config.directory" is unsupported for definition
>   "parameters"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters should be at the same level than services:

```
parameters:
    config.directory: './../../../'
services:
  _defaults:
       public: true
  settings:
       class: Bar\Foo\Service
       arguments: ['%config.directory%']
```